# Laravel cant delete file in remote url using Storage::('s3')->delete($files); but can delete when using aws command

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, minio

I want to delete these files in my laravel like this. But it doesnt work!!

```
use Storage;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function delete()
    {
        $filesToDelete = [
           'http://minio:9100/minio/myapp/1/ImNkE0wwrstgSpzFyruw8.jpeg',
           'http://minio:9100/minio/myapp/1/YFrdE0sarsAcpfFyrifd2.jpeg'
        ];

        // cant delete using this
        Storage::disk('s3')->delete($filesToDelete); 
    }
}
```

But when I try to delete using this command in my bash it works perfectly

```
aws --endpoint-url http://minio:9100 s3 rm s3://myapp/1/ImNkE0wwrstgSpzFyruw8.jpeg
delete: s3://myapp/1/ImNkE0wwrstgSpzFyruw8.jpeg
```

my aws configure list is exactly the same in my project config! 
I can use Storage to upload the files but when I try to delete the files it doesnt work:

```
// Working
Storage::disk('s3')->put('1/ImNkE0wwrstgSpzFyruw8.jpeg', $file);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there anyway to delete these files using laravel??

https://docs.min.io/docs/aws-cli-with-minio
https://readouble.com/laravel/5.4/en/filesystem.html

Comment: What's the output say?

Comment: there is no error or warning output!! It is just ignored!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I think the problem is file path. Try to run as mentioned below.

```
Storage::disk('s3')->delete('myapp/1/ImNkE0wwrstgSpzFyruw8.jpeg');
```

Comment: I did it using Storage::disk('s3')->delete('1/ImNkE0wwrstgSpzFyruw8.jpeg'); without using myapp!! Anyway thanks!! It works!!!

Answer (score 6):

I solving this parsing url, like this:

```
$file_path = parse_url($file_url);
        //return $file_path['path'];
        Storage::disk('s3')->delete($file_path);
```

it works for me.
In your bucket, the files has a key, thath be need to delete file from your php function. to get this the object url be parsed.

Comment: put $file_path['path'] as param in delete function

Answer (score 1):

You are adding wrong file path.In order to remove image form s3 bucket you are not need to give full path of image, Just add root path of image.

**To delete multiple images**

```
        $files = [
           'myapp/1/ImNkE0wwrstgSpzFyruw8.jpeg',
           'myapp/1/YFrdE0sarsAcpfFyrifd2.jpeg'
        ];

        Storage::disk('s3')->delete($files);
```

**Delete single image**

```
        $file = 'myapp/1/ImNkE0wwrstgSpzFyruw8.jpeg';
        Storage::disk('s3')->delete($file);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by this way

```
$file_name='your_file_path';
unlink(storage_path($file_name));
```

Comment: You cannot do this as the files are stored on S3 not locally